# Flutter - Firestore stream snapshot with where not streaming when clause arguments are updated

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My flutter app is using Firestore as a database. I am listening on a stream for data using this:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('cars')
          .where("free", isEqualTo: true).snapshots()
```

The problem with this is that when I change the field free of a car with `free : false` the stream is not updating, probably because of the `where("free", isEqualTo: true)` but if I change the field to `free : true` the stream sends updates...

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to create an index in Firestore.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing?authuser=0#create_a_missing_index_through_an_error_message